# Bulk write to ElasticSearch from Firestore using Google Cloud Functions

Tags: firebase, elasticsearch, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

Currently I am using Firestore for my database and I have a users collection.  Whenever a user document is created or updated to the users collection, a cloud function takes the user document and saves it in Elastisearch.

I am starting to be concerned about the scalability to this architecture.  For example, suppose that several thousand cloud functions started writing documents to Elasticsearch at once, is Elasticsearch going to handle this load.  Is there a better solution to this in Google cloud?

For example, can those cloud functions write the user documents in a queue and have cloud functions at the other end of the queue take a 100 documents and bulk write them to Elasticsearch.

I am new to Google cloud and would appreciate if you give me ideas, videos, and things to read.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ElasticSearch has no limits on number of documents it can have per index but there are some limits such as maximum doc size and bulk writes mentioned in their [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/app-search/current/limits.html#plan-api-limitations-engine-limits).

> Maximum Document Size: 100KB [configurable in 7.7+]
>
> Maximum Indexing Payload Size: 10MB
>
> Bulk Indexing Maximum: 100 documents per batch

As far as I know, Google Cloud has no full text search API.

Talking of bulk writes, if realtime availability (data to be available immediately after adding) if not a concern, then you can store the new documents in Firestore along with a timestamp they were added and a boolean value if a document has been indexes in Elasticsearch.

Then instead of running a cloud function with `onCreate` trigger, you can run a scheduled cloud function every N minutes which will:

1. Query documents which have not been added in Elasticsearch
2. Make batches of 100 (for the 1000/batch limit)
3. Upload them to Elasticsearch

This way you are are more documents per cloud function run so that'll be a bit efficient but if you need your new data to be available immediately then this won't work.

Comment: Data does not need to be sent immediatly from firestore to elasticsearch.  So your idea seems interesting.  However, I see one problem with it.  You must keep a boolean variable in each user document in firestore to let you know if document was copied to elasticsearch.  Once a batch of 100 documents is copied to elasticsearch, you will need to update those user documents in firestore.  Isn't that expensive operation?  Also this approach is only good for update and create.  It is not good for delete.

Comment: @AimnBlbol it costs `$0.18/100K writes`. I have not done any calculations but that still sounds cheaper than running a cloud function for each document.

Comment: What if the user document was deleted from firestore, how is your scheduled cloud function going to know to delete it from elasticsearch

Comment: @AimnBlbol you could run a function using `onDelete` trigger but let's just modify the method above. Let's change the boolean value to a string having 3 possible values, `added, pending, deleted`. When the function runs you can check for 'pending', these are documents to be added and documents with 'deleted' will be deleted.